# How can I adjust the visibility range of a basemap's labels in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, basemap

I have created a map in ArcGIS Pro using an OpenStreetMap basemap. However, in the zoomed out layout that I wish to export, the labels of most towns and cities not visible.

[image: Generated map layout with invisible labels (i.e., towns and cities)]

For better context, I would like to retain the labels from the basemap, even in my zoomed out layout. Is there a way to adjust the visibility range (even if this means that the labels would be much smaller or crowded)?

I can see all the labels I need if I zoom into portions of the map in the Map view:

[image: Visible labels in the Map tab/view]

Answer (score 1):

You can set a "reference scale" for your map, which will display the labels and features at a specific scale even if you zoom in or out.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/map-reference-scales.htm

Doing this should allow you to maintain the OSM labels you see when you are more zoomed in.

Comment: To add to this, individual labels in Pro also have a visibility scale that can be changed by right clicking the layer -> labeling properties -> Visibility Range in the labeling window that opens.